How to translate labels on the y axis in chart.js matrix plugin?
I am using this chart.js extention to create a matrix where I have values from 0 to n on the x axis and labels in string format like "One", "Two", "Three" on the y axis.
https://chartjs-chart-matrix.pages.dev/samples/category.html
I use Transloco library for changing the translations in runtime when the user changes the language but I have no idea how I would translate the labels in a nice way.
As far as I understand the value which you provide in the dataset is then also shown on the y axis meaning that if I wanted to change the labels I would have to loop over the whole dataset and change the strings which is not really good for performance. Does anyone have a better idea on how to do it?

Is changing the language at runtime such a common use case that it needs good performance? In my experience, it's a rare case. We even refresh the page when the language changes, so we don't need to deal with such issues.
